# Problem adding iptables rule

Tags: centos, iptables

I just installed OMSA and need to open up port 1311 to access the web tool.

Here's `iptables` before:

```
[root@mybox ~]# iptables -nvL --line-numbers
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
1      335 38904 ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state RELATED,ESTABLISHED 
2        0     0 ACCEPT     icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
3        0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  lo     *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
4        4   240 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state NEW tcp dpt:22 
5    32795 7454K REJECT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
```

So I added:

```
[root@mybox ~]# iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 1311 -j ACCEPT
[root@mybox ~]# iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 1311 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

And here's the resulting config:

```
[root@mybox ~]# iptables -nvL --line-numbers
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
1      433 45904 ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state RELATED,ESTABLISHED 
2        0     0 ACCEPT     icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
3        0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  lo     *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
4        4   240 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state NEW tcp dpt:22 
5    32941 7486K REJECT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           reject-with icmp-host-prohibited 
6        0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:1311
```

Port 1311 is still being blocked as you can see above.

How do I add a rule and have it go before the deny-all `reject-with icmp-host-prohibited` rule (line #5 under INPUT)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
iptables -I INPUT 5 -p tcp --dport 1311 -j ACCEPT
```

This means: insert this rule before line 5, which is what you want.